# how to retain my filtered data untill i update that particular record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

i have an application in which i am having `start_date` and `due_date` . and i am filtering my table on `due_date` like who are all having due date in couple of days need to show their record eg. today is 25-07-2014 if `due_date` of particular person is on 27-07-2014 the data should get filtered and m displaying it in gridview . i am using the following query to achive it.

```
DECLARE  @DatePartOnly DATETIME
SEt @DatePartOnly = DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE())
select * 
from users 
where DueDate=DATEADD(DAY,2,@DatePartOnly) and TableStatus='Active'
```

but what the problem is the list wont be shown for next day i.e my query is filtering the list based on current date so next day i wont be seeing the records and i need to display these records in gridview until i update that particular row by clicking select command.

my problem is untill i update my filterd list in gridview i need to display it.

please help me to achive this .

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just say where DueDate<DATEADD(DAY,2,@DatePartOnly) AND TableStatus='Active' to show all the records that are still active and haven't been updated and that the duedate is less than 2 days?

Comment: if i say duedate<<DATEADD(DAY,2,@DatePartOnly) AND TableStatus='Active' i will get records of 2days i.e tommorow and day after tommorow but i need records of day after tommorow only from current date.

Comment: is the problem because duedate is a datetime? try this: duedate > DATEADD(DAY,1,@DatePartOnly) AND dueDate < DATEADD(DAY,3, @DatePartOnly) this will show all records for the day after tomorrow no matter the time.

Comment: but what about retaining the records untill i update a particular row???

Comment: then you would need to leave the query open ended and not constrain the data by the date to pick up all the records you missed because the date window has passed.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    declare @FromDate datetime
                    declare @ToDate datetime
                    set @FromDate = DATEADD("d",0,GETDATE())
                    set @ToDate = DATEADD("d",2,GETDATE())
                    select * from users
                    where duedate between @FromDate and @ToDate and TableStatus='Active'
```

i used the above query to acheive my task.

thank you